# MySQL - Newbie question: Which are the PK and the FK for these tables?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 tables:

**Employees T**

emp_id | name | address

**Department T**

dep_id | name

**Salaries T**

emp_id | dep_id | month | year | salary

For each table, what are the primary keys and the foreign keys?

My answer:

**Name of the table | PK | FK|**

- **Employees: emp_id | dep_id**
- **Department: dep_id || emp_id**
- **Salaries: emp_id, dep_id | emp_id,
  dep_id**

Is my answer correct?

Comment: The data model is incorrect.  DEP_ID should be an attribute of Employees (an employee belongs to a department).  Consequently it should be removed from Salaries, affecting the columns which define the composite primary key for that table (EMP_ID, MONTH, YEAR).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Employees` and `Department` tables have primary keys (which you got correct), but no foreign keys.

In `Salaries`, both `emp_id` and `dep_id` are foreign keys.

There's no single primary key on `Salaries`, although `emp_id`, `dep_id`, `month` and `year` could possibly be a composite key (as the combination of these 4 would always be unique, assuming an employee is only salaried once per month by a department :) ).

Comment: And probably emp_id and dep_id both as primary key, in Salaries that is.

Comment: A primary key can be a composite of 2+ columns, so the primary key for `SALARIES` would be: emp_id, dep_id, month, year

Comment: It's homework.  Any speculation about a composite primary key is probably out of scope.

Comment: Henk: emp_id and dep_id would not form a primary key together, because it would have to be repeated for each month of the year.

Comment: Robert, he's l;ooking for the pk for that table 2, I don't think pointing out the only possible valid PK for the salary table is all the fields is out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. The foreign key and primary keys have nothing to do with names. You will need to use the DESCRIBE syntax as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html) to find what the keys are.

Comment: Disagree strongly with Robert, homework is the time to learn how to do things correctly and not make assumptions. This is by far the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the names I would make these assumptions:

```
Employees T

emp_id | name | address
```

**PK:** emp_id
**FK:** none

```
Department T

dep_id | name
```

**PK:** dep_id
**FK:** none

```
Salaries T

emp_id | dep_id | month | year | salary
```

**PK:** none
**FK:** emp_id, dep_id

Comment: That wouldn't work as most primary keys imply unique.  As soon as the employee received a second paycheck it would fail to insert.

Comment: @envalid, it's homework; that's probably outside the scope of the question.

Comment: A primary key can be a composite of 2+ columns, so the primary key for SALARIES would be: emp_id, dep_id, month, year

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the create script of the tables? With only this information, you can't do anything but guessing by the names of attributes...

Comment: It's homework.  The create script is probably not part of the question, otherwise the OP would have provided it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like two tables (Employees and Department) and linking (junction) Salaries table for implementing many-to-many relationship.

As stated in other answers, you need only primary keys for both Employees (PK emp_id) and Department (PK dep_id) tables, no foreign keys.

Table Salaries mast has foreign keys on emp_id, dep_id columns. For primary key you have two choices. Primary Key enforces uniqueness of the column on which they are defined. So, or no primary key at all, or compound primary key (emp_id, dep_id, month, year); the order of columns depends on you needs (select queries).